# PHP Upload file filtering

Tags: php, html, upload

Im trying to write an upload script that only accepts PNG images on upload. The upload script works fine but when I add the png image detection, it breaks.

Here is how I have it set up:

```
if ($_FILES) {

        if ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/png") {

        $target_path = "uploads/";
        $target_path = $target_path . basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']); 

        if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploadedfile']['tmp_name'], $target_path)) {
            echo "The file ".  basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']). 
            " has been uploaded";
        } else{
            echo "There was an error uploading the file, please try again!";
        }

        } else { echo "Not A PNG…";

        }

    }
```

When I upload a PNG image, I get the 'not a png' error - any ideas?

Comment: You are sure it's PNG image, not other format with just .png extension?

Comment: I realize that the question was about the lack of this functioning correctly due to the name typo, however it is worth addressing as others have mentioned that the type string supplied there cannot be trusted. This is absolutely true, and due to the fact you're not checking essentially any other information about the file, this check can easily be circumvented to allow upload of arbitrary code (or anything else) to your system. I advise taking other measures to secure this upload script or there may be security trouble in your near future.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you're referencing the file wrong in the IF statement:

```
if ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/png") {
```

should be

```
if ($_FILES["uploadedfile"]["type"] == "image/png") {
```

("file" needs to be "uploadedfile")

Comment: Thanks, I totally missed that - I'll check it once the timer is up.

Comment: This script does not guarantee that the image actually *is* a png image. Mimetype can be faked with ease.

Comment: Srsly, that was the issue? lol - btw if you want proper PNG validation using PHP-GD, see my post below, nice eyes @Ben D

Comment: Yeah, sorry I just got mixed up with variable names.

Answer (score 2):

I have seen some servers not add the mime type image/png in the $_FILES variable... there is a slightly CPU heavier way:

```
if (@imagecreatefrompng($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"])
```

The performance here will be slightly reduced as you are using the GD library to open the image canvas

If performance or lack of GD library is an issue, simply check the extension:

```
if (strtolower(end(explode('.',$_FILES["file"]["name"])) == 'png')
```

---

**Note**
If you want to use the [imagecreatefrompng](http://php.net/imagecreatefrompng) function, it would be advisable to make sure GD is installed: `if (function_exists('imagecreatefrompng'))`

---

**Important**
If you are cautious about memory usage (which you should be) do this

```
if ($image = @imagecreatefrompng($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"]) {
  // Do something
  imagedestroy($image);
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

1. Never use `$_FILES[...]['type']` for anything. It's just an arbitrary, user supplied string which may or may not have anything to do with the actual file.
2. Therefore, check the MIME type yourself.
3. Enable `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', true);`, which would help you find your particular typo.
4. Get used to *failing early*.

Example for 2 and 4:

```
if (!empty($_FILES['uploadedfile'])) {
    if ($_FILES['uploadedfile']['error'] !== UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
        die('Error during upload');
    }
    if (exif_imagetype($_FILES['uploadedfile']['tmp_name']) !== IMAGETYPE_PNG) {
        die('Wrong file type');
    }
    ...
}
```